# Javascript uint32 math not working?

Tags: javascript

Something weird with uint32 math :

```
a = new Uint32Array([1103515245, 1103527590, 0]);
a[2] = a[0] * a[1];
console.log(a[2]);
```

Gives 2524872960, which is wrong I think, because in C :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned a[3] = { 1103515245, 1103527590, 0 };
    a[2] = a[0] * a[1];
    printf("%u\n", a[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives 2524872878 (and so does Windows Calculator)

So what's up with that?   I'm using Firefox 45.0.1

**EDIT**: Oh and if that is expected, then how do I duplicate the "C" result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because JS doesn't have an Integer type. So `*` does the multiplication in 64 bit floats. But these don't have enough precision for the result:

```
/* Exact math */ 1103515245 × 1103527590  =  1217759518843109550
/* JavaScript */ 1103515245 * 1103527590 === 1217759518843109600
                 Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === 0009007199254740991
```

If you want to do integer multiplication, use [`Math.imul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul):

> The `Math.imul()` function returns the result of the C-like 32-bit
>   multiplication of the two parameters.

```
a[2] = Math.imul(a[0], a[1]); // -1770094418
a[2];                         //  2524872878
```